# City Name Fetching Via GetLocality

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to fetch the current city name from server. I have achieved this in my following code. the problem is when i try to fetch the current city name and if internet connection slow at that time application is being force closed.  can anyone help me how to Prevent my application being force closed.i just want to toast a simple message like "Slow internet connection". help me to get it.

```
public String getCity() {
    String city = "";
     try
        {
         Geocoder geo=new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
         Log.i("TAG","latitude"+ latitude+"\n logitude"+longitude);
            List<Address> addresses=geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults);
               if (addresses.size() > 0) 
               {
                   Log.i("TAG",""+addresses.size()+"-"+addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                   city=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
               }

        }// end of try
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            city="error";
        }
    return city;
}
```

Comment: put that code in AsyncTask

Comment: logcat will be useful

Comment: yes you should put your logcat here..

Comment: yes i have already called the method in AsyncTask as follows...

protected ArrayAdapter<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

if(gps.canGetLocation()){
          
          city=gps.getCity();
          if(city.equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
          {
           network_enabled=false;
          }
                   
         }else{
 
          gps_enabled=false;
          
       }
  return null;
  }

Comment: i can not put log cat right now as my internet connection is not slow currently. i will put it once i get it. sorry for that.